# What exactly the "BatchID" is in tracking Data Views?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

Lately, I have been trying to figure out the most generic query for getting tracking data into one table. As suggested in the [SQL Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_find_subscribers_with_no_opens_or_clicks_ref.htm&type=5), I have been using this join:

```
...
FROM _Sent s LEFT JOIN _Job as j ON s.JobID = j.JobID 
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID  and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
```

My results show the same email send, with the same JobID, sent exactly at the same time, to the same subscriber, but with different batch numbers. On top of that, only the first record has an open date:

[image]

According to documentation, `BatchID`   is "The batch ID number for any batches used in the send" - but what does it mean, really? And how should the  `BatchID` be treated in queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BatchID is the 'grouping' of the email inside the batches sent to the Mail Transfer Agent for sending.

In a Bulk send environment, this means the following: (numbers are all arbitrary)

1. Assume that the MTA has a max of 100 emails per batch
2. You have an audience size of 1000 emails
3. You would have 10 batches inside your send, meaning for this jobid, you would have batchid of 1 through 10 inside this field.

In a Triggered or Journey Send environment the BatchID is a bit different.  The BatchID is used to differentiate between sends when the JobID, ListID, EmailAddress, etc. (the usual primary keys) are all identical, it will increase the BatchID by 1.

so for instance if its a Welcome trigger (keeps same Job, List, etc.) and the recipient has 2 different accounts, but use an identical subscriber - then first send would be `BatchID = 1` and the second send would be `BatchID = 2`.

Comment: In my context it comes from JB - but still not sure how to understand this.. it’s one subscriber, same subscriber key, and sent date is exactly the same - so why 5 different records, whit 5 different batches?

Comment: It would appear that the email was sent 5 times. The batch is there to help differentiate Trigger sends when all the other data points are identical.

Comment: Ahh, so the sent time would mean “published time” in this context? Thanks!!

Comment: Sent time would be time it was sent still. It looks like it was sent 5 times at the same time. So likely if this was unintentional I would review your Journey re-entry settings and entry filters, etc.

Comment: Thanks - l’ll test this scenario and see what I get!

Comment: I too was looking at this today. From my investigation the first part of @Gortonington's response seems spot on! However, I believe that the BatchID behaves the same for Journey. 
For a single email send for a de-duped audience admitted to a journey via DE Entry source (scheduled automation), I have BatchID counting all the way up to 145. The largest number included in a batch appears to be 100.