# What exactly is BatchID in _Sent data view?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to identify unique identifier for email activities? I was thinking to use combination of SubscriberKey, JobId and EventDate as unique identifier but when we looked at historical email activities we found that there are some email activities which has same SubscriberKey, same JobID and same event date. Somehow same email has been sent to same subscriber as part of same email send job at the same time.

I am using SQL activity to query all the email activities from Sent,Job and Subscribers data view. I want each record in the target data extension including records with duplicate SubscriberKey and JobId. With current Primary Keys(SubscriberKey, JobID and EventDate), SQL activity gives duplicate primary key error.

I am just wondering if I can use BatchId along with SubscriberKey, JobID and EventId as a primary key on the target data extension. Note: I can see combination of these these 4 primary keys is unique currently, but just want to confirm if this would be the case in future as well. Based on the description of the BatchId, it doesn't looks like it will be unique across all the emails being sent. so can someone shed some light on the BatchID property of Sent data view and can it be used to solve above problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/278748/12730

Comment: Great minds and all that jazz @EazyE.