# Advanced journey reporting via SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder

Currently we send a newsletter to numerous data extensions based off a contacts region. All reporting is currently done out of a report from the catalog. I'd like to move the newsletter to a journey to leverage some of the additional activities native to journey builder. The only way for this to work for us is to be able to track the region in a DE field. So instead of reporting out of the catalog on each send by data extension, I'd like to do a single data extension with the region being tracked in a region column.

For reporting, what would could I do to include the region from the DE? This would be to break out Opens/Clicks/CTR etc by region.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Do you have a region field in your sendable data extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a Sendlog.

If region is already available for use in the email, e.g. for personalization, then all you need to do is log it at the time of send. Write into a data extension that can be interpreted in the context of the existing out of the box logging, i.e. the data views.

You can:

a) either build a data extension of type "based on a template" and use [SendLogging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&language=en_us&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5), but I am not sure how far you will get with the customizations suggested below.

b) or you insert an InsertData Call into your email. In this case, make sure you track all the things that make a send event unique in your DE. (subscriberkey, listid, batchid, jobid).
see here: [What exactly the "BatchID" is in tracking Data Views?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278742/what-exactly-the-batchid-is-in-tracking-data-views)

This DE will be filled after processing of the actual email sendout. You can match it with open, click, bounce etc. table and thus can deduce e.g. "click by region" using SQL.

The primary keys in your DE would be:
SubscriberKey,JobId,ListId,BatchId

Assuming you have an AMPScript variable *@region* defined somewhere in your email,
this could go into your email.

```
%%[/* Message Logging */]%%

<span style="display:none">%%[


IF _messagecontext == "SEND" and jobid > 0 then
InsertDE("mySendlogDE",
"SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey,
"Email", emailaddr,
"EmailName", emailname_,
"SentDate_Servertime", Now(),
"JobId", jobid,
"ListId",listid,
"BatchId", _JobSubscriberBatchID,
"region",@region

)
ENDIF
]%%</span>
```